# Python Selenium: Check if a new file in the download folder is added

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have this when I press on a link it downloads to the download folder.
my Url looks something like so

```
url='https://vle......ac.uk/pluginfile.php/2814969/mod_page/content/16/Statistics_for_Business_and_Economics_----_%28Unit_I_Introduction%29.pdf'

driver.execute_script("window.open('%s', '_blank')" % URL)
```

Where the URL is a pdf file that I am trying to download.

I want to write a code that waits until number of files in the download folder increases to move on to the next itteration in the loop.

I wrote this code:

```
def wait_till_number_of_files_is_byound_the_current_file():
    path_download=r'\\Mac\Home\Downloads\*'
    list_of_files = glob.glob(path_download)
    a=len(list_of_files)
    while len(list_of_files)==a:
        time.sleep(1)
        list_of_files = glob.glob(path_download)
```

In my for loop I also tried this code

```
item = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(lambda driver: driver.execute_script("window.open('%s', '_blank')" % URL))
```

but this made the file being pressed infinitely not only once.

Comment: Post your URL and complete code

Comment: @AbiSaran I post how it looks

Answer (score 0):

The best way, to get around this (I hope there would be a better way) is to use the following function

```
def download_wait(directory, timeout, nfiles=None):
    """
    Wait for downloads to finish with a specified timeout.

    Args
    ----
    directory : str
        The path to the folder where the files will be downloaded.
    timeout : int
        How many seconds to wait until timing out.
    nfiles : int, defaults to None
        If provided, also wait for the expected number of files.

    """
    seconds = 0
    dl_wait = True
    while dl_wait and seconds < timeout:
        time.sleep(1)
        dl_wait = False
        files = os.listdir(directory)
        if nfiles and len(files) != nfiles:
            dl_wait = True

        for fname in files:
            if fname.endswith('.crdownload'):
                dl_wait = True

        seconds += 1
    return seconds
```

In my for loop, I wrote the following

```
for url in hyper_link_of_files:
        # Click on this link
        driver.execute_script("window.open('%s', '_blank')" % url)
        # time.sleep(2)
        download_wait(r'\\Mac\Home\Downloads', 10, nfiles=None)
        time.sleep(2)
        # move the last download file into the destination folder
        Move_File(dest_folder)
```

I will share my Move_File function for reference to those who are interested in moving the downloaded file into a new destination

```
def Move_File(path_needed):
    # Get the working directory of the downloads folder
    path_download=r'\\Mac\Home\Downloads\*'
    list_of_files = glob.glob(path_download) 
    latest_file = max(list_of_files, key=os.path.getctime)

    # Copy to the new file into the destination
    path_destination=os.path.join(path_needed,os.path.basename(latest_file))
    shutil.move(latest_file,path_destination)
```